# Are there $A,B, C, D$ vector spaces such that $A \oplus B \cong C \oplus D$, and $A\cong C$, but $B\not\cong D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I remember an exercise from Roman's *Linear Algebra*, but now I can't locate it in the book. Anyway, I think it asked to give examples of $A,B, C, D$ vector spaces such that $A \oplus B \cong C \oplus D$, and $A\cong C$, but $B\not\cong D$.

I feel like I must be forgetting some additional part of the problem, because the above is impossible, right?

Comment: Hint: Consider what happens if the dimensions of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all countable, but $D$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: A-ha! Thank you, that has been bothering me in the back of my head for months.

Comment: [Exercise 10, page 107](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101762/) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a vector space V and decompositions $V=A\oplus B = C\oplus D$ with $A$ isomorphic to $C$ but $B$ is not isomorphic to $D?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101762/how-to-find-a-vector-space-v-and-decompositions-v-a-oplus-b-c-oplus-d-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would post an answer based on Tobias's hint in this community wiki:

If $A, B, C$ are countable-dimensional, but $D$ is finite dimensional, then by cardinal arithmetic, $A \cong A \oplus B \cong C \cong C \oplus D$, but $B \not\cong D$.